# Can I used the command line to disable settings in Yosemite that have made my Mac visible?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

Recent changes to my machine as the result of an upgrade to Yosemite (OS X 10.10) have made my machine visible on [Bluetooth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151481/4395) and [Bonjour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151485/4395), where it was not visible before.

Is there a command line way to disable/enable the relevant features so that my machine can be restored to "invisibility" to these services (e.g. when I'm in a less secure environment)?

Answer (score 6):

### Bonjour

Prior, to Yosemite this could be done via `launchctl`, so using:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

would turn Bonjour off, and to turn it back on:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

Unfortunately `/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder` is not found on Yosemite.

A bit of digging and this seems to work for Bonjour:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

**NB:** *I'm not clear if this means it stays off, it should given `launchctl` behaviour but I've have **not** had time to test it and determine if anything else in the system will turn it back on.*

### Bluetooth

Presuming you're talking about your Mac's built-in bluetooth and not a third party adaptor, then:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

*Lists all services, usually show Bluetooth as 'Bluetooth DUN'*

```
killall blued
```

*Kills the bluetooth server process*

#### Launchctl commands

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

*Unload the bt daemon*

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

*Reload the bt daemon*

```
launchctl start com.apple.blued
```

*Restart blued daemon*

Comment: Is there a way to just take BT out of "advertising mode" (or is that what the above does)?

Comment: Came across this while looking to reconnect my trackpad to bluetooth. Even with the above bluetooth wouldn't shut off (`killall blued` couldn't find the process).

This article did the trick for me: http://www.macissues.com/2015/05/07/overcome-bluetooth-devices-not-staying-paired-after-sleeping-os-x/

Replicate what happens at boot:

`sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport`

`sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by notacouch, cppl's answer doesn't work on Yosemite as killall blued doesn't find the process.

As recommended on notacouch shared URL's you need to do this:
Open the Terminal utility

Run the following two commands:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport;
sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
```

When done, if Bluetooth is off then turn it back on and choose your devices from the Bluetooth menu. As a quick tip, you can select both of the commands above and then drag the selection to a Finder window, to create a text clipping of them in a convenient location (such as your Desktop). You can then quickly run the commands by dragging the clipping to a new Terminal window.

For more details follow [this URL](http://www.macissues.com/2015/05/07/overcome-bluetooth-devices-not-staying-paired-after-sleeping-os-x/)